# Can I use the verb "attached" for a piece of information supplied in the email body?

Tags: verbs, word-usage, email

> Please find attached the detail for my application.

Is this sentence correct if I supply the detail in the email body, not in a separately attached file?

Comment: An attachment is considered attached. If you say you have attached detail, then the reader will be looking for an attachment in addition to what ever detail you have put in the body of the email. You will likely get a response, "thanks for the email, but I didn't see an attachment."

Comment: "See details below" is a common phrase for conveying that there's more info further along in the current document.

Comment: As explained in jlovegren's answer, the sentence is grammatically correct. But, as explained in Mitch's comment, it would not be true in the situation you describe. In connection with email, "attached" has come to refer to a specific mode of transmission of files along with messages, and that mode is different from placing the file in the body of the message.

Comment: I'd 86 the "please find," since attaching something to an email is not a game of hide and seek, with the possibility of not finding the attachment.  Just say, "Attached is . . .." Or, "Please look at the attached __________." In a similar vein, instead of saying "I would like to thank Susie," just say, "Thank you, Susie . . . ," or "I owe a big thank-you to Susie . . .." Minor point; no biggie.

Answer (score 1):

As you have it written is correct, though you would use "the details".

*Attached* is functioning as a participial adjunct, not a verb, and so it has variable placement. Compare:

> **Attached** please find the documents you have requested / **Lying on the table** you will find the documents...
>
> Please find **attached** the documents... / You will find **lying on the table** the documents...
>
> Please find the documents you have requested **attached** / You will find the documents you have requested **lying on the table**

Answer (score 0):

"Please find the details attached to my application" seems to me correct, if it is given appending to the application.There is a grammatical error in asking "an information" for, INFORMATION is an UNCOUNTABLE noun.The alternative is "A piece of information" : AZEEZ TANUR

Answer (score 0):

First of all it should be  **details** (you should use the plural, not *detail*).

You normally attach  a file in the email.
Hence, I would rephrase it:

> I attach a file detailing my information. (or *resume*, or *curriculum vitae*)

or:

> Please find attached the details **of** my application (not details **for**)

Comment: This may be a stylistic preference, but I'd use a different verb tense in your first rephrasing: _I **have attached** a file detailing my information_.